# leer todos los datos de un documento de excel

Tags: java

Quisiera saber como puedo leer todos los datos de un documento de excel en java hice un algorimo pero cuando leo un valor de tipo int termina el programa.

```
package com.veliz;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nombreArchivo = "juan.xlsx";
        String rutaArchivo = "C:\\Users\\veliz\\Documents\\tareas\\9 periodo\\programacion orientada a objetos\\" + nombreArchivo;
        System.out.println(rutaArchivo);
        String hoja = "Sheet1";

        try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(rutaArchivo))) {
            // leer archivo excel
            XSSFWorkbook worbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            //obtener la hoja que se va leer
            XSSFSheet sheet = worbook.getSheetAt(0);
            //obtener todas las filas de la hoja excel
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

            Row row;
            // se recorre cada fila hasta el final
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                row = rowIterator.next();
                //se obtiene las celdas por fila
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                Cell cell;
                //se recorre cada celda
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    // se obtiene la celda en espec�fico y se la imprime
                   //en esta parte cuando ya imprime los valores me deja de 
                  //funcionar no me obtiene el valor de tipo int solo String 
                  //inclusivamente cambio los valores en exel a String y no me 
                  //funciona hay algun metodo para convertir todo a string en 
                  // java
                    cell = cellIterator.next();
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + " | ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: el problema es que cuando pido un valor de tipo int me saca del programa

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: por favor, pone toda la informacion de la pregunta en la pregunta. Usa el boton [edit] para agregar la informacion que falte. que quiere decir me saca? sale algun error?

Comment: es que cuando leo los valores en exel me funciona bien pero solo los valores de tipo string y cuando ya empieza a leer un valor de tipo int el programa deja de funcionar algun metodo que le pueda añir para convertir todos los datos a string

Comment: donde falla?? y agrega por favor la informacion en la pregunta.. no en comentarios...

Comment: cuando ya voy a imprimir los datos me saca del programa y solo me imprime los datos de tipo String

Comment: debugueaste?? obviamente el problema es getStringCellValue...

Comment: si lo hice y ahí es el problema pero que puedo hacer en este caso

Comment: te fijaste en el manual que otras opciones tenes para org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.getStringCellValue????

Comment: si pero no me funciono intente con getRichStringCellValue() y me realiza lo mismo

Comment: ya lo hice y me tira valores de 0 1 y 3 en las celdas ahora que le puedo agregar al codigo

Answer (score 1):

Para saber el tipo de dato que hay en la celda deberías usar algo como lo siguiente:

```
......
switch(celda.getCellType()) {

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

            if( DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(celda) ){

               System.out.println(celda.getDateCellValue());

            }else{

               System.out.println(celda.getNumericCellValue());

            }

            break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:

            System.out.println(celda.getStringCellValue());

            break;

        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:

            System.out.println(celda.getBooleanCellValue());

            break;

        }
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

el manual dice:

> Cells can be numeric, formula-based or string-based (text). The cell
>   type specifies this. String cells cannot conatin numbers and numeric
>   cells cannot contain strings (at least according to our model).

Las celdas pueden ser numericas, basadas en una formula o de texto. El tipo de celda especifica esto. Las celdas string no pueden contener numeros y viceversa (segun el modelo de esta clase).

Entonces, antes de imprimir, tenes que usar: `CellType` para saber que tipo de celda tenes, y luego de eso buscar el valor segun el tipo de celda.

Fuente: [ACA](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellType--)

Comment: ya pude amigo pero como hago para delimitar los datos

Comment: no se a que te referis

Comment: amigo estoy realizando un proyecto final de clases pero ya realize algo que se me complico pero ocupo ver si me podes ayudar en algo mas  es de asignasion de clases y ocupo un metodo o una forma de asignarle a cada clase un tipo de aula segun la que le adapte mejor a dicha clase crees poder ayudarme con eso no se como la verdad

Comment: @jveliz no se a que te estas refiriendo. Tenes que ser mucho mas claro con las preguntas. Esta respuesta (o la otra) no te sirvio? porque no marcaste ninguna como aceptada. Si tenes otra pregunta, por favor hacela en el sitio y yo (o alguien mas) si sabe como, procurara contestarla.